# htaccess to remove extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want all request to `abcxyzpqr.do` to be sent to `abcxyzpqr`  i.e all request with extension should be to same name but without the extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Replace html with your file extension, eg: php, htm, asp

It should work the way you want it.

credits/ more info:
http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2007/08/19/removing-file-extension-via-htaccess/